# How to clear after floating images in LaTeX?

Tags: image, latex

I'm trying to text-wrap floating images in LaTeX, using code like the following:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{images/image.png}
\caption{This is the caption.}
}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure
```

This works fine most of the time (creating an image that floats on the right-hand side), but sometimes LaTeX does not properly clear after the image, and it leaves an open column for another page or two. How does one remedy this, or ideally, does LaTeX have a function similar to `clear: both` in CSS?

There is the `\clearpage` command, but it's not appropriate when there's no natural place to break to a new page near the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try to manually set the height of the figure using the optional argument of wrapfigure

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[lineheight]{alignment}{width}
```

where lineheight is the number of text lines which shall wrap around the image.

Comment: No such luck. This results in it not being a constant column of whitespace, but still having whitespace corresponding to the lineheight every few lines.

Answer (score -1):

I still don't have a good answer to this question, but the solution for now is to not use `wrapfigure` at all. Using only `figure` solves the problem of open columns, but it's not the most ideal solution. Any other answers are still welcome, but I'll post my half-way solution here for those who might also need it:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{images/image.png}
\caption{This is the caption.}
\end{center}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I don't see how this wraps the text at all.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it doesn't wrap text, but it does clear images properly, instead of having pages full of columns with nothing on it. If there is a better answer, I'll be very happy to know about it.